# how to track referral link on android

Tags: android, firebase, google-play, google-play-console, referrals

I've an android app available on google play store and I want to create a referral system to engage users to share.

The app already has an share button which creates a link like:

`Hey, have a look at this app...https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tomatedigital.&amp;referrer=utm_source%3Dapp_referral_USERID`

this way i can monitore through google play console and firebase dashboard which links generated downloads, it show the information pretty nice but i need to automatically get it.

would be awesome if i could get it inside the app so i show the sign up for to the user with the referer already filled... but i strongly think it's impossible

but if somehow i can get this information from google play console I could write a script which runs once per day and update the bonus to users with most shares

is that possible? how can i implement a referral system like this?

Comment: why not just make a call to a url shortening service that offers tracking on button click? https://www.crazyegg.com/blog/url-shorteners-analytics/

Comment: @KaranHarshWardhan because it has nothing with the problem i want to solve

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with the [Google Play referral API](https://developer.android.com/google/play/installreferrer/igetinstallreferrerservice) which has [some more docs here](https://developer.android.com/google/play/installreferrer/)